# Spring-Data for OrientDB Using template

Tags: java, graph, spring-data, orientdb, graph-databases

I am new to orient database and want to make a small project using graph model of it, but it is very hard to find any docs related to graph model using spring-data. Are there any demo project for reference that would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Mustanish Altamash, have you already see https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb and https://github.com/megadix/orientdb-spring maybe can help you

Comment: Hi idacrema, thanks for replying, I have seen that github link but nothing is clear from above link.I was hoping for a proper documentation as there is for mongodb and couchbase.I am looking for graph model of it.